# Difficulties with Boost.Python installation on Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10 and Python 3.64)

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-python

I am trying to install Boost.Python since I need to use some Python code in a C++ application. I followed the instructions on boost.org for the installation of boost 1.74.

I did bootstrap and `.\b2`

Everything seemed to go fine until I couldn't find in the `stage\lib` folder any boost python library (vc142). It looks like b2 can't find any python installation, but I think I am using the python path:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64`

I am doing something wrong??
Can you please help me make the hello word example work?

BOOST 1.74 FOLDER

[image]

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does that directory contain the Python header files and DLLs?

Comment: Folder: DLLs, Doc, include, Lib, libs, Scripts, share, tcl, Tools, LICENSE, NEWS, python (application), python.pdb, python3.dll, python36.dll, python36.pdb, pythonw, pythonw.pdb, vcruntime140.dll

Comment: This is the content of the folder

Comment: In addition Visual studio 2019 gives me the error: impossible to open the file "boost_python27-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1.71.lib"

Comment: Edit your question with this information, and be sure to include the output of the B2 command.

Comment: From your screenshots (don't do that in the future) it looks like the python extension was built, so are you absolutely certain your stage\lib directory does not contain any file whose name contains "python" ?

Comment: OK! So what I can do in the future?

Comment: Yes, I am sure there is not python file in the stage/lib folder